# Force Chrome to open new tabs in specific window

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I have a separate Chrome window for time tracking using toggl.com. When other applications open new Chrome tabs, I would like those new tabs to open in my main Chrome window, not in the separate window I have created just for toggl.com. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I am using Linux, although I'm not sure that matters.

Comment: Generally I am using the Toggl application now so the issue does not arise, but when it does I use your answer, so I'll accept it.

Comment: In my experience it opens in the last used window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to achieve this:

1 - When the `new tab` open it will always opens in the `chrome` window which is last active or last minimized, means you have to open two chrome's window and always have to `active` the window in which you want to have your new tabs to open.

2 - You have to install different browser so that you don't have to care the `active` chrome's window.

That's all you can do.

Comment: There is a plugin that will open a tab in a specific window, but I want to do this from a shell script... so I want them named.

Comment: @mcr what is the name of this extension you speak of? I've been searching for something which can open tabs in a specific window but have not been able to find it!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but opening the first window as a popup using simple HTML does it:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" 
target="popup" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','popup','width=600,height=600'); return false;">
Link Text goes here...
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a workaround for this issue.
If there is a Window you do not want new tabs in, open it as an Incognito window.

If you use this often for just one site (like for daily time tracking), create another Chrome shortcut.
At the end of the file path add --Incognito .
For example Start In:
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application" --incognito https://superuser.com/

This will open your site up in an Incognito window. No new tabs will bother you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).